# Couchbase SDK cannot decode binary document

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I am trying to fetch BinaryDocuments uploaded by cbworkloadgen from Couchbase 4.0.0-4051 Community Edition. Couchbase Java client version is 2.4.1.

The exception given by decoder is -

```
WARNING: Decoding of document with BinaryTranscoder failed. exception: Flags (0x0) indicate non-binary document for id pymc0, could not decode., id: "pymc0", cas: 1486468016723525632, expiry: 0, flags: 0x0, status: SUCCESS, content size: 2048 bytes, content: "".

    com.couchbase.client.java.error.TranscodingException: Flags (0x0) indicate non-binary document for id pymc0, could not decode.
com.couchbase.client.java.error.TranscodingException: Flags (0x0) indicate non-binary document for id pymc0, could not decode.
        at com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.BinaryTranscoder.doDecode(BinaryTranscoder.java:32)
        at com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.BinaryTranscoder.doDecode(BinaryTranscoder.java:26)
        at com.couchbase.client.java.transcoder.AbstractTranscoder.decode(AbstractTranscoder.java:42)
        at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$1.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:274)
        at com.couchbase.client.java.CouchbaseAsyncBucket$1.call(CouchbaseAsyncBucket.java:270)
        at rx.internal.operators.OnSubscribeMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(OnSubscribeMap.java:69)
```

I use following to get document -

```
AbstractDocument<?> doc = destinationBucket.get((String) row.key(), isJson ? JsonDocument.class : BinaryDocument.class);
```

For JsonDocument things work okay. row is AsyncViewRow.

What am I doing wrong? Can someone please tell me? Or is this a bug related to incorrect value in flags field?

Comment: You can add more info to get more precise answers, like what actually are to trying to save and fetch, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Well, due to want of time, I changed the approach since I was also getting out of memory errors when iterating a view asynchronously on a bucket million documents.

As regard to this issue, it may be that he flags field set by cbworkloadgen without -j option for each document is 0 and the BinaryTranscoder thinks it's not a binary document because of this value. I got around the problem by using N1ql instead of doing get(). However, I am not sure if this is an issue with cbworkloadgen where it's not setting correct flags.

Answer (score 0):

You can not decode binary documents on your own. If you save something that implements Serializable, it will be serialized and saved to Couchbase and you can retrieve the same easily. But if you fire a N1QL query and try fetching the binary data, you won't be able to decode it. This is something Couchbase doesn't support yet. You can do the same with Json docs.

Comment: @geraldss https://forums.couchbase.com/t/converting-byte-value-retrieved-using-n1qlto-java-object/11147 You can have a look. I am not much into java sdk, but only spring-couchbase-cache.

Comment: rohanagarwal -- these N1QL functions are not related to Java.

Comment: Just to clarify, I was not using N1ql but using the get() provided by the SDK. The get() in CouchbaseAsyncBucket class refers to the flags and proceeds to decode the document (Binary or Json for example).  However, the flag value (0x0) is rejected by BinaryTranscoder. I was wondering whether this is a problem with the Couchbase workload generator or whether I missed out something.